# Найти уникальные элементы двух динамических массивов

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Дано два динамических массива одинаковой размерности. Нужно вывести уникальные элементы. Мой код сравнивает элемент первого массива со всеми элементами второго массива и выводит его столько раз сколько он не совпал с элементами второго массива. Как сделать так, что бы элемент выводился 1 раз и учитывал элементы второго массива тоже.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Mas(int** mas1, int** mas2, int &n)
{
cin >> n;
*mas1 = new int[n];
*mas2 = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
(*mas1)[i] = rand() % 10;

}
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
(*mas2)[j] = rand() % 10;
}
}

void PrintMas(int* mas1, int* mas2, int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
cout << mas1[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
cout << mas2[j] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
}



void inclusiv(int** mas1, int** mas2, int &n) {
int inc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
if ((*mas1)[i] != (*mas2)[j]) {
inc++;
}
}
}
int *newMas = new int[inc];
int Move = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
if ((*mas1)[i] != (*mas2)[j] ) {
newMas[Move] = (*mas1)[i];
Move++;
}
}

for (int i = 0; i < inc; i++) {
cout << newMas[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
delete[](newMas);

}


int main () {
int n = 0;
int *mas1 = NULL;
int *mas2 = NULL;
Mas(&mas1, &mas2, n);
PrintMas(mas1, mas2, n);
inclusiv(&mas1, &mas2, n);
delete[] mas1;
delete[] mas2;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: какже вы любите эти указатели на указателей, когда  просто нужен один указатель и   2  размера

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

/*
    Функция проверки вхождения элемента в массив

    p - одномерный массив
    e - элемент
    size - размер массива
*/
template<typename T>
bool Check(T* p, const T& e, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if (p[i] == e) return true;

    return false;
}

/*
Функция проверки пересечения двух массивов

    a - указатель на первый массив
    sizeA - размер первого массива
    b - указатель на второй массив
    sizeB - размер второго массива
    с - ссылка на указатель на массив результат
    sizeC - ссылка на размер массива результата
*/
template<typename T>
void Intersection(T* a, std::size_t sizeA,
    T* b, std::size_t sizeB, T*& c, std::size_t& sizeC)
{
    sizeC = 0;

    std::size_t tempSize;
    if (sizeA < sizeB) tempSize = sizeA;
    else tempSize = sizeB;

    c = new T[tempSize];

    for (std::size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeA; ++i)
    {
        if (Check(b, a[i], sizeB) && !Check(c, a[i], sizeC) )
        {
            c[j] = a[i];

            ++sizeC;
            ++j;
        }

    }

    T* p = new T[sizeC];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeC; ++i)
        p[i] = c[i];

    delete[] c;
    c = p;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a1[] {1, 3};
    int a2[] {1, 2, 3};

    int* a3 = nullptr;
    std::size_t size;

    Intersection(a1, 2, a2, 3, a3, size);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    std::cout << a3[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```